# Запятая при встрече "и" и подчинительного союза

Tags: запятые, спп

Поясните, пожалуйста, по какому правилу ставится запятая перед и после "и" в следующих предложениях?

Крепкий был человек Гуляев, и, когда он вернулся на Урал, за ним тянулась блестящая слава миллионера.

Почему-то про него говорили, что он прекрасный художник, и, когда у него умерла мать, бабушка отправила его в Москву, в Комиссаровское училище.

Этот новорождённый барин особенно раздражал Самгина, и, если б Клим Иванович был способен ненавидеть, он ненавидел бы его.

В голове стало легче, яснее, всё как-то сгустилось, и, пока в голове происходило это сгущение, на улице тоже стало тише.

Спокойно-красивую Елизавету Михайловну она разглядывала большими умилёнными глазами, и, когда та ласкала её мягкой и нежной рукой, у неё сладко замирало сердце.

Лиза пошла безлюдной площадью, и, когда ноги её стали тяжело срываться с круглых лысин булыжника, она вспомнила, как возвращалась этой площадью солнечным днём после первой встречи с Цветухиным.

Answer (score 2):

Странно, вы приводите в вопросе **все** предложения, изложенные [в правилах Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140).

**§ 36. Запятая на стыке двух союзов.**
4. При «встрече» соединительного союза ***и*** и подчинительного союза возможны следующие случаи:
3) запятая ставится и перед союзом ***и***, и после него, если союз соединяет два простых предложения (причем после придаточной части не следует вторая часть двойного союза)…

*Спокойно-красивую Елизавету Михайловну **она разглядывала** большими умилёнными глазами,(1) и,(2) когда та ласкала её мягкой и нежной рукой, у неё сладко **замирало сердце.***

(1) Запятая ставится между двумя простыми предложениями:
*Она разглядывала, и замирало сердце.*

(2) При двух рядом стоящих союзах (сочинительный союз **и** и подчинительный союз **когда**) запятая между союзами ставится только в том случае, когда "удаление" придаточного предложения не требует перестройки главного предложения:
*Спокойно-красивую Елизавету Михайловну она разглядывала большими умилёнными глазами, и у неё сладко замирало сердце.* [Придаточное предложение изъято.]

Comment: В тех же правилах Розенталя есть предложение со следующей пунктуацией: "Он давно уже уехал, и где он теперь, никто не знает", в котором после придаточной части не следует вторая часть двойного союза. Вопрос: как объяснить отсутствие запятой перед придаточной частью?

Comment: @Максим  Запятой нет, может, потому, что при изъятии "где он теперь" теряется смысл, который сохранится только при перестановке: "Он давно уже уехал, и никто не знает, где он теперь".

Answer (score 0):

Во всех вышеперечисленных случаях постановка запятой определяется правилом, подробно изложенным в ["Грамоте"](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_188).

Если говорить кратко, то пунктуация определяется следующим алгоритмом:

1. Определить, есть ли у главной части, которой подчинена придаточная, соответствующее указательное местоимение, например "тогда".
2. Если ответ положительный, то оба союза — сочинительный и подчинительный — образуют цельную конструкцию, к которой и относится указательное местоимение. Проверить данное утверждение можно методом убирания придаточной части, который, как Вы понимаете, не срабатывает. В ином же случае придаточная часть относится к простому предложению, вводимому сочинительным союзом, в нашем случае "и", и обособляется с обеих сторон.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая ставится и перед союзом И, и после него, если союз соединяет два простых предложения:

Крепкий был человек Гуляев, и, когда он вернулся на Урал, за ним тянулась блестящая слава миллионера.

первое простое предложение - [Крепкий был человек Гуляев]

второе простое предложение - [за ним тянулась блестящая слава миллионера]

Если союз И присоединяет не простое, а сложноподчиненное предложение, то запятая после союза И не ставится, а только перед ним:

Он давно уже уехал, и где он теперь, никто не знает.

простое предложение - [Он давно уже уехал]

сложноподчиненное предложение - [где он теперь, никто не знает].

Comment: Аналогично можно считать предложение [когда он вернулся на Урал, за ним тянулась блестящая слава миллионера.] сложноподчиненным. Или нет?